# is it possible Running loop on Docker Swarm or k8s?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers, docker-swarm

Let's say need to run 10 docker rclone for upload, but with 100 different source (10 concurrently).

```
docker run --rm -d bitnami/rclone -- rclone copy SOURCE01: DST01:
docker run --rm -d bitnami/rclone -- rclone copy SOURCE02: DST02:
x
x
docker run --rm -d bitnami/rclone -- rclone copy SOURCE10: DST10:
```

if any of the above finished, container will be deleted and I have to start another one with SOURCE11: and DST11: and so on, and so on.
is there anyway to automate this?

Note: I have 100 Source and 100 Dst

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

A solution with docker swarm:

```
docker service create --mode replicated-job --replicas 100 --max-replicas-per-node 10 bitnami/rclone -- rclone copy SOURCE{{.Task.ID}}: DST{{.Task.ID}}:
```

Replicated jobs run each task once and then consider it complete assuming it doesn't fail. I am assuming that the "10 concurrent" means, or can be re-interpreted to mean, some reasonable number per node. If you actually wanted 10 concurrent and had a 10 node swarm, then --max-replicas-per-node could be set to 1.

Finally, I am assuming/hoping that docker service template expansion works on the command line, in which case the golang `{{}}` syntax can expand .Task.ID which will be the number of each task. I am not, frankly, familiar enough with the go tempalate package to know if you can zero pad the numbers. If not I'd just add the zeros explicitly and do the first 99.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions!, will deep-dive into swarm and task.id behaviour.
your assumption is correct on 10 concurrent means. :)
altough I can't mark your answer as correct one, since I need to try and error your suggestion.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: .Task.ID return random string, not number :(

Comment: damn, I know its a random string for `--mode global`, but as its a number for `--mode replicated` I thought that would apply for `replicated-job` too.

Comment: altough, name of jobs included numerical, but it's servicename.{number}.jobname, so i just included it on --env, and parse it using awk ;)